# Only can Click the Button for one time per day

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a  button with numeric values of 100. A total number will be displayed on  the page. When I click on the "Add 100", it will update and display on the page. I want the button to  click only once per day. For example you can't click the button for a second time again. Here's my html code. How can I only make the button clickable once per day? (24 hours)?

```
   <div>Total : <span id="total">0</span></div>
   <input class="add" data-amount="100" type="button" value="Add 100" />


$(document).ready(function() {
$('.add').click(function() {
 $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) + 
 parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
 });
})
```

Comment: Let me make this clear: client-side restrictions are as safe as using a toothpick as your door lock. With that being said, if this is only for visual hints, you can store the timestamp of the previous click in localStorage, and disable the button accordingly. You can also including the previous timestamp in the document while serving the page, or fetch the previous timestamp via XHR. Lots of options to choose from.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫  you mind giving an example?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use server-side JavaScript to make it work when you close the page, but if the page doesn't close or reload, ***ever***, you do this:

```
var dayClicked = true;

$("#button").click(function() {
    if (dayClicked) {
        alert("Error!");
    }
    else {
        variable += 1;
        dayClicked = false;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        dayClicked = true;
    }, 86400000);
});
```

This'll add one to `variable`, then make the `#button` element show an error message for the next day (86400000 seconds).

Comment: There won't be any error message - the button will be disabled.

Comment: No worries! Glad to help!